# The server QTcpSocket "breaks" too soon and the client doesn't receive all the data, any idea why?

Tags: qt, tcp, client-server

I wrote a client/server TCP/IP program and it worked fine until the server generated a larger file. At that point it broke, not all the time, but often enough to make it a real problem. I wrote a small version with just the TCP/IP and it reproduces the problem which I find quite impressive.

I tried all sorts of things to fix the problem, but I'm not too sure what to do next!

```
/*
 * Test showing that at times a socket close() + exit(0) prevents all the
 * data from reaching the client.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

void
client()
{
    QHostAddress a("192.168.2.1");
    int port = 4004;
    QTcpSocket socket;
    socket.connectToHost(a, port);
    if(socket.waitForConnected())
    {
        // if we get here then we can just copy the output of the child to Apache2
        // the wait will flush all the writes as necessary
        if(!socket.waitForReadyRead())
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: waitForReadyRead() timed out.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        // buffer somewhere to check the output validity
        FILE *f = fopen("/tmp/out.html", "w");
        if(f == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: could not create /tmp/out.html file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        for(;;)
        {
            char buf[64 * 1024];
            qint64 r(socket.read(buf, sizeof(buf)));
            if(r > 0)
            {
                fwrite(buf, r, 1, f);
            }
            else if(r == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: an error occured while read()'ing from the socket.\n");
                break;
            }
            else if(r == 0)
            {
                // no more data (since our socket is blocking this really
                // only happens when no more data is available)
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(f);
        return;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "error: client could not connect to server.\n");
    exit(1);
}


void
server()
{
    QTcpServer s;
    QHostAddress a("0.0.0.0");
    if(!s.listen(a, 4004))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: server is not able to listen, port 4004 not available?\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid_t pid(0);
    for(;;)
    {
        if(pid > 0)
        {
            int status;
            if(waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG) == pid)
            {
                pid = 0;
            }
        }
        s.waitForNewConnection(-1);
        if(pid > 0)
        {
            int status;
            if(waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == pid)
            {
                pid = 0;
            }
        }
        QTcpSocket *socket(s.nextPendingConnection());
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            // this makes it work a bit better but we still have the
            // early disconnection
            int optval(1);
            socklen_t optlen(sizeof(optval));
            if(setsockopt(socket->socketDescriptor(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, optlen) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "warning: could not mark the new connection with keepalive flag.\n");
            }

            // we are the child, write in the socket and close it
            QFile f("example.html");
            f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
            QByteArray buffer(f.readAll());
            f.close();
            socket->write(buffer);
            // the sleep makes it slow, but it doesn't make any difference
            //sleep(2);
            socket->flush();
            // extra sleep/flush don't make any difference
            //sleep(1);
            //socket->flush();
            //sleep(1);
            //socket->flush();
            // the read doesn't seem to fix anything
            socket->waitForReadyRead();
            socket->disconnectFromHost();
            delete socket;
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            if(pid == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: could not create child process to handle the socket.\n");
            }
            socket->close();
        }
    }
}


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        client();
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-s") == 0)
    {
        server();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [-s]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

I used a CMakeLists.txt file to compile the server & client. Once compiled we have one executable: tcp-bug. Start it with -s as the server. Then start the same executable in a different console without the -s. I wrote a shell script to test repetitively because it generally doesn't happen the first time, although it's generally in less than 20 hits.

There is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(tcp-bug)
find_package(Qt4 4.8.1 REQUIRED QtCore QtNetwork)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
include_directories(${QT_INCLUDES})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable(tcp-bug tcp-bug.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tcp-bug ${QT_LIBRARIES})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "tcp-bug")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES ".swp$;/BUILD/")
include(CPack)
```

And my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for g in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
do
    for f in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    do
        BUILD/tcp-bug
        if [ `stat -c %s /tmp/out.html` -ne 41812 ]
        then
            echo "Error occured! Iteration: $g - $f"
            ls -l /tmp/out.html
            exit 1
        fi
    done
done
```

Note that the script expects a file of exactly 41,812 bytes available in the .tar.gz found on the following page (you can also create your own example.html file, what the server reads and sends to the client):

http://linux.m2osw.com/breaking-tcpip-simple-clientserver-implementation-qt

Comment: may i suggest a link to an answer i gave on server and client with Qt?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762222/multi-client-server-tcp-application-using-qt/13762650#13762650

Comment: Yes. Client/Server works fine when in a forever loop. In my case, the child (created with the fork) goes inside the `if(pid == 0)` block. If you look closely, I have an `exit(0)` at the end of that block. This mechanism is important for two main reasons: security so each child is in its own process (each has its own connection to the database,) and memory management (each child uses more or less memory and at times a HUGE amount... so we want to exit the child and not get the server to grow forever.) I'd bet that without that exit() call it would work fine.

Comment: actually there was already on my answer ;)

Comment: @AlexisWilke did you ever solve this? I am struggling with the same issue.  hooking up slot to ReadyRead() grabs all the data sent by the server, but trying to grab all the bytes available upon asking a question which polls (waitforbyteswritten) does not.

Comment: @Rachel, yes in the sense that I fixed the problem, no in the sense that I could not get the Qt implementation to work. If you'd like, I have that in my open source project, look for tcp_client_server.cpp/h and feel free to use that code directly. There is also a UDP client/server in there if you need. https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/lib/

Comment: I got exactly the same problem. `disconnectFromHost` is supposed to flush all the remaining data to the socket, but it seems it's just not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer as I think many people will run in similar issues and I have resolved it... although that was by not using Qt at all.

The problem is that Qt opens the socket and puts it in `O_NONBLOCK` mode and because of that, it will ignore the proper shutdown signals/flushing. It gets closed immediately when you hit `exit(0)` and nothing gets flushed on the client's end so the server doesn't get the final data and vice versa.

At the time, I tried to remove the `O_NONBLOCK` thinking that could help, but for some reason (at least around 2012), it would not really go back to a blocking socket. So that was useless. The blocking can also cause other issues if you're not careful with the socket (i.e. your app. could block trying to read or write from a socket).

My solution was to implement my own event library, now called [eventdispatcher](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher). This library supports TCP, UDP, Unix sockets (DGRAM/Stream) and also can be used to watch file changes, Unix signals, thread termination, inter-thread communication. All those connections support a timer also a timer can be used on its own (without a socket connection). Each connection also supports a message implementation meaning you can use the library as an RPC system. The message can be our internal text based message (optimized) or JSON (larger messages). This has worked beautifully and I really don't regret leaving Qt behind for all the network features.

In order to support these types of connections inside a Qt application, I also have a special Qt connection which uses the Qt socket (X11 really) so it can still be used with Qt. It's just a tad bit different. With eventdispatcher, you must remove all the connections before it quits cleanly, so it makes it a lot easier to properly clean up the sockets since it becomes explicit.